# Securely deleting data from SQL Server logs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transaction-log

Is there a good way to purge data from a particular DB's *.LDF?

A little background... I'm a SysAd, not a DBA. I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 for one of my applications and I'm not particularly concerned about the size of the logs. However, in order to meet certain DSS compliance, I occasionally have to purge certain data from the database and ensure that it is in no way recoverable.

I'm under the impression that if I go in and DELETE the particular entries I should be fine as far as the *.MDF is concerned. But I still need to make sure there is no way to recover the data from logs.

Comment: Are you using Transparent Data Encryption? Which recovery model is the database in?

Comment: No Transparent Data Encryption; full recovery model. Should I switch to a Simple recovery model? I'm doing 3rd-party backups using CommVault

Comment: I guess you are not asking about reading the Log and deleting certain entries from log file. and otherwise only way you can assure any time data is not recoverable from log file is by getting rid of that log file and assigning new log file at regular interval. how frequently you are planning to purge the transaction log? or in your case can you ask DBA to create such JOB and run at off load hours?

Comment: Are you also taking into account older backup images that still contain the deleted data?

Comment: Hopefully this will not happen often, only in the event that someone mistakenly puts the wrong data on the wrong server. The SOP I've figured out so far is to find the initial creation time of the bad data, bring down the application, perform a delete of all that info, and purge all CommVault backups from after the initial spill date. 

Now I'm trying to figure out exactly how to ensure the data is not recoverable from the DB in any way.

Comment: If you are not using Transparent Data Encryption, deleted data is easily recovered from MDF files. When you drop a table or delete/truncate the data, the data is actually left behind, only metadata is deleted. Data isn't gone until those data pages are overwritten with new data, and seeing as you can't determine where new data is written, you can't be sure it has been overwritten.

Comment: @MarkS.Rasmussen Even if you are using TDE isn't the data theoretically recoverable if the Database Encryption Key hasn't been rotated and destroyed?


Right now I think I may have to remove the data from the DB, somehow purge the data out of the transaction-log,  perform a backup, shred the MDF and LDF, and restore from backup.

Comment: Since you are going to find the time of creation of bad data, an alternative might be to restore the database up to that point in time, which will recreate data files and reinitialize logs, after which you'll just need to delete the logs that may have been backed up between then and now.

Comment: @mustaccio if the data were to go unnoticed for a week, then we wouldn't want to lose other data that had been entered since then.

Comment: @Doct0rZ Yes - if someone were to find the certificates from the master database, the data encrypted by TDE would be retrievable. This is however way more complicated and at some point you'll need to consider the level of security needed. Just adding TDE will make it so much more difficult to retrieve the data compared to raw unencrypted MDF files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Server log contains all the data that was written to the database (in some form). So, you are right to be concerned about it.

The log is a ring buffer made up of virtual log files (VLF). Once a VLF is not needed anymore, it can be reused. However it will not be reused until the "write head" comes around to that VLF again.

The only difference between simple and full (with a few small exceptions) recovery model is how quickly a VLF is "not needed anymore". If you use full recovery mode, a VLF is "needed" at least until a log backup has been taken. (A full backup never clears the "needed" flag of a VLF.)

The only way to force a VLF to be overwritten is to first make sure that it is not needed anymore and then pump enough transactions into the database that the VLF gets reused. That however is probably not acceptable to you.

Another way to force the data out is to shrink the log file. If you can take downtime, follow this process:

1. Set the database to READ_ONLY
2. Run the CHECKPOINT command.
3. take a log backup (if in full recovery)
4. make sure other log-readers (replication, CDC, ...) have caught up
5. set the database to READ_WRITE
6. create a new log file
7. empty the original file migrating the data to the new (`DBCC SHRINKFILE`, there should not be any data left to migrate at this point, but you still need to execute this step.)
8. drop the old log file
9. take another log backup (if in full recovery)

You still need to test this, but this should get you to where you need to be.

If you can't take downtime, follow the same process without setting the database to READ_ONLY. However, you run the risk not to be able to have a complete clean cutover, but if you do this regularly you still should be OK.

---

Note, as some of the commenters have mentioned, a delete does not actually remove the data from the MDF files either. However, that can be dealt with in a similar fashion:

1. rebuild all indexes on the offending table(s) (or better all tables)
2. create a new file
3. empty the old file, migrating the data to the new file using `DBCC SHRINKFILE`
4. drop the old file

Step 1 is necessary as the file migration does not change page contents, so single deleted rows might survive the move. Rebuilding the indexes should use new pages.

---

Additional notes:

The log cleanup has to happen after the data file cleanup as there is a chance that the data file cleanup moves some of the data into the log file.

Index rebuild operations and also a lot of data access operations utilize tempdb, so you have to shred that too. Tempdb is recreated on server restart, so you can stop the SQL Server service, delete the tempdb files and then start the service again.

Finally, this all causes a lot of blocks (~ database pages) to be unlinked from existing database files. This unlinking (due to file shrinkage or the deletion of files) does not force those blocks to be overwritten. So it is recommended to create the new files in the above processes on a separate disk and afterwards securely wipe the original disk.

Comment: Downtime isn't usually an issue. Generally, the data is sensitive enough that upon recognition, we will lock everyone out of the application until the data has been deemed non-recoverable.

Comment: Your method for removing old data won't actually be fully secure. Rebuilding does not necessarily overwrite the unallocated pages, so they may still be left behind. Dropping the old file won't zero it out, it'll just remove the SQL + NTFS metadata for the file, so it can still be restored by most recovery tools, after which you could go about retrieving non-overwritten data from the MDF file itself. If you do copy to a new disk and wipe the old, sure, that should get rid of it :)